# Java parsing last part of a string

Tags: java

I have three strings.

```
0:0:0-0:0:1
0:0:0-3:0:0-1:2:0
0:0:0-3:0:0-3:2:0-3:2:1
```

I am trying to do an exercise where I am parsing the string to output only the last part after the `-`, i.e. respectively:

```
0:0:1
1:2:0
3:2:1
```

I have tried of doing it by getting all the characters from the end of the string up until `-5`, but that won't always work (if the numbers are more then 1 integer). `lastStateVisited` is my string

```
lastStateVisited = lastStateVisited.substring(lastStateVisited.length() - 5);
```

I thought of splitting the string in an array and getting the last element of the array, but it seems inefficient.

```
String[] result = lastStateVisited.split("[-]");
lastStateVisited = result[result.length - 1];
```

What is a way I could do this? Thanks

Comment: "I thought of splitting the string in an array and getting the last element of the array, but it seems inefficient." Is efficiency particularly required here? Do you have concrete requirements around that? (You can use `String.lastIndexOf` in this case, but I'd generally urge using a simple solution and then optimizing after measuring it and finding it to be too inefficient.)

Comment: Please post the code you have already tried so we can point you in the right direction. We are not a free code-writing service ;)

Comment: @Michael I've added the code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
String l = "your-string";
int temp = l.lastIndexOf('-');
String lastPart = l.substring(temp+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirement concentrate around your need of acquiring the sub-string from the end till `-` appears first time.

So why not first get the index of last `-` that appeared in string. And after than extract the sub-string from here till end. **Good option. :)**

```
String str = "0:0:0-3:0:0-3:2:0-3:2:1";
String reqStr = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('-')+1);
```

`reqStr` contains the required string. You can use loop with this part of code to extract more such strings.